# python замена символа пробела .replace(" ","") не срабатывает. Получить '4690' из '4 690¤'

Tags: python

Имеется строка, которая была взята с сайта

```
4 690¤
```

Нужна строка следующего образца: `4690`
Отсек последний символ [:-1], а вот с пробелом никак не могу решить, `.replace` не срабатывает

```
if(div_old!=[]):
        price_old=div_old[0].text[:-1]
        price_new=price_old.replace(" ","")
        print("Старая цена:",price_new)
```

Comment: "``.replace`` не срабатывает"... А ``div_old[0].text[:-1]`` срабатывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price_new = ''.join(c for c in '4 690¤' if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: `c.isdecimal()`

Comment: @jfs хм, никогда не обращал внимания на разницу. Спасибо.

Comment: @jfs не работает

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо

Comment: @danilshik: что "не работает"? Какой конкретно код? Что вы ожидали получить? Что вместо этого происходит?

Comment: @danilshik [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @jfs ваш код это исправление к коду Sergey Gornostaev?

Comment: @danilshik: верхний индекс: `'²'.isdigit()` против   `'²'.isdecimal()` (`int('²')` выбросит ValueError).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdecimal, '4 690¤'))
'4690'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = ''
for i in '4 690¤':
    if i in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']:
        res += i
```